# Is there a way to setup dummy database to test a .NET Framework 4.7.2 repository/database integration?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, integration-testing

I am trying to set up integration testing between the repository and database for a .NET Framework app, which has already been built. I have been trying to find a way to setup and seed a test database or in memory database that I could use to run some tests against, but don't see much in terms of .NET Framework apps.

I have seen that there is a `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory` library that accomplishes what I need, but it is only available for .NET Core projects running version 6.0. I have also found little to no similar mention of this being possible on a .NET Framework Project, but imagine that there has to be a way.

My work on this legacy app is my first foray into the .NET world, so I may be misunderstanding things from my research on this topic. Is it possible to set up a test/in memory database for integration testing a .NET Framework app? If so, what are the best practices for doing so?

Comment: Have you thought about using [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html)? Also see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/?tabs=netcore-cli

Comment: @MatthewWatson I have looked into it but I have only been able to find information regarding .NET Core usage of SQLite, particularly with Microsoft's `InMemory` library. I also have limited experience with using SQLite, so may be missing the connection between .NET Framework and SQLite. Looking at your link to Microsoft Docs, that library seems to have a dependency on .NET Core, if I understand correctly.

Comment: You can use a SQL Server.  I usually create a database which is an mdf file.  Once the database is created you can deattach the file from server (or use a localdb).  The file can then be copied in Windows and reattached so you have a test database that is always the same.

Comment: If you're more familiar with MS SQL (based on your comments re: sqlite, etc.), you can dev with [SQL Server Express LocalDB](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver15). Working with SQL Server Express LocalDB and Visual Studio: [Create a database and add tables in Visual Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/create-a-sql-database-by-using-a-designer?view=vs-2022). You can then configure the appropriate connection strings for debug/testing, integration/unit testing, vs production, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to test a pure SQL database, my advice would be to setup a local MSSQL Server for testing your application and its integration with the database. I don't know what kind of project you have, but assuming it is a `ASP.NET` project (Web API p.e) you should already have well defined `Models` which work like the building blocks of the tables you will use on your database. EF Core essentially maps those models as tables in the database.

### Define a new connection to a local MSSQL Server

#### 1. Define the service on `Startup.cs`

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(opt => opt
            .UseSqlServer(_config.GetConnectionString("Name"), builder =>
             {
                  builder.EnableRetryOnFailure(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), null);
             }));
}
```

The `EnableRetryOnFailure` will make sure your application retries a connection to the database server in case of a connection error.

#### 2. Define a `ConnectionString`

Go to `appsettings.json` and add

```json
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "Name": "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=myDb;Trusted_Connection=true"
  }
```

This example uses Windows authentication, but you can use `SQL Server Authentication`

#### 3. Install MSSQL Server Management Studio

It helps a lot for visualizing your database tables

`Entitiy Framework` **in-memory** is available for `.NET 5.0`. My advice to use a local database instance with MSSQL is Microsoft's own recommendation, as mentioned in their website

> The EF in-memory database often behaves differently than relational databases. Only use the EF in-memory database after fully understanding the issues and trade-offs involved, as discussed in Testing code that uses EF Core.